# Rails — Action Mailer conventions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, delayed-job

Thinking about implementing of (a little bit) smarter notification system in my project.
What I'd like to do is emailing user about few new let's say private messages *once* within certain range of time rather than each time he gets new message.
Of course there will not be without **delayed_job**, but here I've got a couple of etic questions about ActionMailer:

1. How many logic you can put in Mailer class?
2. Can I perform database queries within Mailer class methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest keeping ActionMailer logic to a bare minimum: just rendering the email and doing the actual delivery.

Yes I realize this makes the delayed_job logic slightly more complicated since you can't just send a delayed email, but it keeps the logic where it should be.

Answer (score 5):

So you'll be sending an email "Digest" of the various "Notifications" that occur in the system.

I suggest you move the logic that right now sends an email using ActionMailer to a Notification class. This will persist the notification with a flag set to false for `notified` (or similar).

Then, have a job run daily (or similar) that sends a digest email to people who have notifications they need to receive.

Comment: Do you mean I need another model and controller for that purpose?